# Getting the "feels like" temperature based on wind and temperature in python

Tags: python, math, weather

Based on the wind-speed (meter per second) and temperature (in Celsius), how can I calculate the real "feels like" temperature.

What I want is something like, feels_like(3, -5) to return -9, based on the formula on the button of http://om.yr.no/forklaring/symbol/effektiv-temperatur/ (sorry, English translation at http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=no&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fom.yr.no%2Fforklaring%2Fsymbol%2Feffektiv-temperatur%2F )

Comment: The English term for this is "wind chill."

Comment: See [windchill table using nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735469/table-using-nested-loop) which is about computing [windchill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_chill#North_American_and_United_Kingdom_wind_chill_index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick..

```
In [1]: feels_like = lambda w, t: int(13.12+(0.615*float(t))-(11.37*(float(w)*3.6)**0.16)+(0.3965*float(t))*((float(w)*3.6)**0.16))

In [2]: calc_feels_like(3, -5)
Out[2]: -9
```